# Tensorflow warning when importing TFLearn

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

I'm using the CPU version of tensorflow and I pip installed to learn and when I try to import tflearn I get the error:

> WARNING:tensorflow:From
>   C:\Users\farbo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py:263:
>   colocate_with (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and
>   will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating:
>   Colocations handled automatically by placer.

I've tried updating everything twice
I've tried reinstalling everything
I'm running python 3.6.8

please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, this is not an error but just a *warning*: reading closely, you'll see that it *warns* you that a command currently used in the code will be removed in a *future* version of Tensorflow.

So, the good news is that you can continue working for the time being, but you should be getting ready for the possibility that your TFLearn code will not work in a *future* version of Tensorflow.

The reason for this (and for the fact that you were not able to make it go away, no matter how many times you re-installed stuff) is apparent from the [TFLearn repo](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn); looking closely again, you'll see that the project is not under active development, with most of the stuff there being unchanged for 2-3 years now. This means that the project does not stay up to date with new modifications of Tensorflow, which is running underneath, hence such deprecation warnings are not a surprize.

So, to make a long story short:

- You should not worry for the time being (except of course if other *errors* pop up later)
- For (present & future) stability of your TFLearn code, you might want to stick to Tensorflow **1.2.0**, which is the latest version tested with TFLearn (see the [Release notes](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/RELEASE.md)).